# how to do forward and backward rolling at the same time in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I need to check if the current value is higher than the next two and the previous three values. Otherwise, it passes the previous number.

Ex:

| date | pos |
| --- | --- |
| 2007-01-01 | 3.0 |
| 2007-01-02 | 5.0 |
| 2007-01-03 | 6.0 |
| 2007-01-10 | 11.0 |
| 2007-01-11 | 9.0 |
| 2007-01-20 | 8.0 |
| 2007-01-21 | 10.0 |
| 2007-01-22 | 13.0 |
| 2007-01-23 | 4.0 |
| 2007-01-27 | 2.0 |
| 2007-01-28 | 1.0 |
| 2007-01-29 | 2.0 |

to

| date | pos |
| --- | --- |
| 2007-01-01 | NA |
| 2007-01-02 | NA |
| 2007-01-03 | NA |
| 2007-01-10 | 11.0 |
| 2007-01-11 | 11.0 |
| 2007-01-20 | 11.0 |
| 2007-01-21 | 11.0 |
| 2007-01-22 | 13.0 |
| 2007-01-23 | 13.0 |
| 2007-01-27 | 13.0 |
| 2007-01-28 | 13.0 |
| 2007-01-29 | 13.0 |

I know how to do backward rolling and forward rolling separately. But can't figure out how how to do it at the same time.

Comment: Looks like you just want to populate `NA` for first row. Is this correct? Please double check.

Comment: What output do you need? Can you provide some examples? What if the value is higher or lower? What results do you expect?

Comment: The table was changed when posted. Btw i changed it

Comment: So what is the logic that makes 2007-01-21 to be 11 then?

Comment: @DanailPetrov, it should use the previous number if condition is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to replace the values that do not pass your conditions with `nan` then use `ffill` to cast the previous values forward.

In this case we are using an expanding window for the first condition with a minimum period of 4 and for the second we invert the data and do a rolling window of 2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2007-01-01',
  1: '2007-01-02', 2: '2007-01-03', 3: '2007-01-10', 4: '2007-01-11',
  5: '2007-01-20', 6: '2007-01-21', 7: '2007-01-22', 8: '2007-01-23',
  9: '2007-01-27', 10: '2007-01-28', 11: '2007-01-29'},
 'pos': {0: 3.0, 1: 5.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 11.0, 4: 9.0, 5: 8.0,
  6: 10.0, 7: 13.0, 8: 4.0, 9: 2.0, 10: 1.0, 11: 2.0}})

df.pos = np.where((df.pos.ge(df.pos.rolling(len(df), min_periods=4).max())) & 
         (df.pos.ge(df.iloc[::-1].pos.rolling(2).max())),
        df.pos,np.nan)
df.ffill()
```

Output

```
    date    pos
0   2007-01-01  NaN
1   2007-01-02  NaN
2   2007-01-03  NaN
3   2007-01-10  11.0
4   2007-01-11  11.0
5   2007-01-20  11.0
6   2007-01-21  11.0
7   2007-01-22  13.0
8   2007-01-23  13.0
9   2007-01-27  13.0
10  2007-01-28  13.0
11  2007-01-29  13.0
```

Comment: That's awesome!